# my Signup controller won't display email text fields.

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have been trying to programmatically create two separate view controllers in which I have a login, and sign up view controller. While my initial view controller, Login allows me to see the email/password text field, my sign up controller does not. I have plugged in the correct information however when I run my application, it is blank. I will post my code below, can anyone help me solve this issue?

```
   let emailTextField: UITextField = {
        let e = UITextField()

        let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes:
            [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])

        e.textColor = .white
        e.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
        e.setBottomBorder(backGroundColor: GREEN_Theme, borderColor: .white)


        return e
    }()

    let passwordTextField: UITextField = {
        let p = UITextField()

        let attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Password", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white])
        p.textColor = .white
        p.isSecureTextEntry = true
        p.attributedPlaceholder = attributedPlaceholder
        p.setBottomBorder(backGroundColor: GREEN_Theme, borderColor: .white)

        return p
    }()

  override func viewDidLoad (){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme

    func setupFileComponents() {

            setupEmailField()
            setupPasswordField()
        }
    func setupEmailField() {
            view.addSubview(emailTextField)

            emailTextField.anchors(top: nil, topPad: 0, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: view.leftAnchor, leftPad: 24, right: view.rightAnchor, rightPad: 24, height: 30, width: 0)
            emailTextField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        }

    func setupPasswordField() {
            view.addSubview(passwordTextField)

            passwordTextField.anchors(top: emailTextField.bottomAnchor, topPad: 8, bottom: nil, bottomPad: 0, left: emailTextField.leftAnchor, leftPad: 0, right: emailTextField.rightAnchor, rightPad: 0, height: 30, width: 0)


        }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you have functions inside of the `viewDidLoad` function? Where are you calling those `setupXXX` functions?

Comment: @rmaddy In my previous view controller I have those functions inside the same exact area and it works fine. should I place them elsewhere?

Comment: 1. Why are they inside `viewDidLoad`? 2. Where are they called? You need to answer those two questions.

Comment: @rmaddy I was watching a tutorial video, and it taught me how to create those fields in my initial view controller. However when I try to mirror it into my sign up page, they don’t work the same. To be honest I’m very new to coding and just figuring it out. With that being said, I don’t know why or where something should be.

Comment: Move methods `setupFileComponents()`, `setupEmailField()` and `setupPasswordField()` to controller so they will be on the same level as `viewDidLoad()`. Then, in `viewDidLoad` call `setupFileComponents()`.
Also, possibly another issue: From what I see, you set width to 0 for text fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move setupFileComponents, setupEmailField, setupPasswordField out of viewDidLoad then you have to add te calls in viewDidLoad like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad (){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = GREEN_Theme
    setupFileComponents()
    setupEmailField()
    setupPasswordField()
}
```